# how to get model values in javascript

Tags: javascript

testModel

```
public class testModel
{
  public int ID{get; set;}
  public string name{get; set;}
}
```

cshtml code

```
@model IEnumerable<testModel>
var lstModel = Model.ToList();
<div id="mainOfferDiv">
@for(int i = 0; i<lstModel.Count(); i++)
{
}
</div
```

In js file i want to get list of testModel data which is there in cshtml file, I tried with below

js file

```
var listModel = document.getElementById("mainOfferDiv");
```

Suppose lstModel contains list of 10data i want to get same in js file

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+style+title+tooltip+anchor+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: It is not clear what does not work when you do `var listModel = document.getElementById("mainOfferDiv");` you perhaps want to add .childNodes or something?

Comment: I think you should learn the basics first, otherwise things will get really confusing. CSHTML only exists server-side.

Comment: mplungjan 
Sorry for question is not that proper, and Asif give me proper output thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take your entire server-side model and turn it into a Javascript object by doing the following:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
```

In your case if you just want the FloorPlanSettings object, simply pass the Encode method that property:

```
var floorplanSettings = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.FloorPlanSettings));
```

another way is

```
Classs property ---
        Name = "Raj",
        IsAuthenticated = true,
        LoginDateTime = DateTime.Now,
        Age = 26,
        UserIconHTML = "<i class='fa fa-users'></i>" 
---------------------------------
```

js in cshtml

```
var Name = @Model.Name;  
var Age = @Model.Age;
var LoginTime = @Model.LoginDateTime; 
var IsAuthenticated = @Model.IsAuthenticated;   
var IconHtml = @Model.UserIconHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you Asif
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); worked for me